# DrRacket 6.8 will not open on Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: macos, scheme, racket

I recently downloaded and installed the dmg for Racket 6.8 for my MacBook Pro running OSX Sierra. I mounted the image and copied the Racket folder to /Applications. Then I double clicked on the DrRacket.app folder and nothing happened. Then I tried to open it from the command line and I get this error:

```
$ open DrRacket.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Racket v6.8/DrRacket.app
```

Am I missing a dependency or a configuration somewhere?

Comment: [Here is the relevant GitHub issue.](https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/1470) It seems like one of the main reasons it hasn’t been fixed is because people are having lots of trouble simply reproducing it. If you can provide information that would allow other people to get a clue into what’s happening, it’d be very helpful.

Comment: @AlexisKing Thank you for the link to the Github bug. I added my information to the thread there and also provided a trace file. Hopefully that will help. There is a gist of the trace output here: https://gist.github.com/gorauskas/f370679d6caf614684fd3f80bc5cdb67